# TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition: Access to the path '...\AppData\Local\Temp\[fileName].tmp' is denied

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am using Team Foundation Server 2010. I created a build controller and agent on my local and turned it into a build machine. But none of the build definitions which work perfectly fine on the other build machine, succeed on this one. As soon as the build process starts, if fails and gives the following error:

***"TF215097: An error occurred while initializing a build for build definition: Access to the path '...\AppData\Local\Temp[fileName].tmp' is denied."***

I checked the events in "Process Monitor" and there was no unsuccessful access attempts logged there. What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

1. Clean the Cache folder on client computer. The folder path is: C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Team Foundation\3.0\Cache.
2. Clean the Cache folder on Server machine. The folder path is: C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Team Foundation\Web Access\Cache

Comment: Hi Cece, thanks for your answer, but it didn't work. There is only one machine and it's a desktop application.

Comment: Did you clean both the cache folders above on your TFS AT machine? Also, try to create a new build definition in current team project to queue a build and check the result.